# Convert google spreadsheet structure to dictionary

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some cells arranged like this:

[image]

And I want to convert them to an object like this:

```
{
  'd/': {
    'dhome/': {
      'duser/': {
        'ddownloads/': {
          'ffile.txt': 'Contents of file'
        },
        'ddocuments/': {
          'fprgm.py': '# python'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So any key that starts with `d` is a directory, and any other that starts with `f` is a file, but the first character isn't part of its actual name.

Does any anyone know how I could achieve this?

Comment: I would approach this by building a JSON string representation of the object (there are no arrays, so that makes it a bit easier) and then `JSON.parse()` that string to the object. Have you tried that approach? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried and say where you have difficulties?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this works for me. It might not be very efficient, but it does the job.

```
function getSpreadsheet()
{
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
}

function getRange(r)
{
  return getSpreadsheet().getRange(r);
}

function getDirs()
{
  const range = getRange('folders!A1:Z');
  const raw_s = range.getDisplayValues()
                .map(function(vals)
                {
                  return vals.map(function(val, i, arr)
                  {
                    val = val.trim();

                    if (val == '')
                    {
                      return null;
                    }

                    return [val, i];
                  })
                  .filter(function(val)
                  {
                    return val != null;
                  })
                  [0];
                })
                .filter(function(vals)
                {
                  return vals != null;
                });

  let struc = tree_from_list(raw_s);

  return struc;
}

function tree_from_list(list) {
    var list_node = list.shift();
    var depth = list_node[1];
    var root = {name: list_node[0], children: []};
    var tree_node;
    var cur_nodes = []; 
    cur_nodes[depth] = root;
    while (list.length > 0) {
        list_node = list.shift();
        tree_node = {name: list_node[0], children: []};
        depth = list_node[1];
        if (cur_nodes[depth - 1] === undefined)
            throw 'invalid list!';
        cur_nodes[depth - 1].children.push(tree_node);
        cur_nodes[depth] = tree_node;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly answer. More like a direction to solve the problem.

Your input looks almost as a valid [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML):

```
root:
  home:
    user:
      downloads:
        file_txt: "Contents of file"
      documents:
        prgm_py: "# python"
```

You can parse YAML into JSON with many tools. For example:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/javascript-yaml-parser/

```
yaml_string = 
`root:
  home:
    user:
      downloads:
        file_txt: "Contents of file"
      documents:
        prgm_py: "# python"
`

var object = YAML.eval(yaml_string);

console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Output:

```
{
    "root": {
        "home": {
            "user": {
                "downloads": {
                    "file_txt": "Contents of file"
                },
                "documents": {
                    "prgm_py": "# python"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json

[image]